# cannot get css list to display inline

Tags: css, menu, inline

Cannot for the life of me figure out why the top menu/search won't show up inline.  It should be lined up in the red top bar.  Anyone?  Thanks! 
http://www.dparisdds.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
  display: inline-block; <------------ here
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

Comment: bingo! that fixed it perfectly.

Comment: Be aware `inline-block` will render as `inline` in IE7. May or may not be an issue. THE MORE YOU KNOW (PING)!

Comment: Yup, you can use float:left for IE7 instead.